# An error occurred during client rendering in asp.net using sql reporting

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I`m beginner in sql reporting. When I strat to create sql reporting and then finish it. I build and successfully deploy this project, but when I want to view report it show me like this.

Please check this link for picture1
http://i58.tinypic.com/2n9c08p.jpg
and when I click n report1 it shows me like this 
picture2
http://tinypic.com/r/2qk57v8/8

It shows me enter login name and password. 
I enter my windows credentials , but not work. 
How I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It say's: Enter a username and password to access the data source.

So i guess the report is trying to connect to the data source (like a sql server?) and has no credentials available in the report. Try submitting your credentials to connect to the used sql server or make sure the credentials are supplied within the report itself.

Comment: which crediteianls  sql server creditianls or windows ?

Comment: I would say sql server credentials.

Comment: Can you edit the report on the reportserver itself? This is done by going to http://yourserverhere/Reports . There it should be possible to 'edit' the report itself. Can you check your connectionsettings there? It is also possible to set a sql-user and sql-password in your report-settings. Try to do it like that.

Comment: Another possibility is to work with a shared datasource. Then you use this in all your other reports as well.